# Is there a formal concept to name source->process->sink

Tags: apache-flink

In Flink, one job can have multiple `source->process->sink` data processing,eg

`val env = StreamExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment env.setStreamTimeCharacteristic(TimeCharacteristic.ProcessingTime) env.addSource(new Source1()).name("Source1").addSink(new Sink1()).name("Sink1").setParallelism(1) env.addSource(new Source2()).name("Source2").addSink(new Sink2()).name("Sink2").setParallelism(1)`

I would ask whether there is a formal concept/name to name such read-process-write processing logic? A flink job could be composed of multiple such pipelines

Comment: An ETL pipeline?

Comment: ETL was also the first thing came to my mind - but I would tend to associate this with a BATCH process even though this is not clearly stated: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extract,_transform,_load

Comment: Thanks @OneCricketeer and tobish, but I don't quite favor ETL, since ETL is too big concept. I want a concept for only a piece of read-process-write pileline(one job could contain multiple such pipeline.),which is a smallest pipeline unit .

Comment: That's the formal name for what you're asking though. Flink calls it a pipeline and, yes, can be multiple, but the overall process is extract (not read), transform (not process), and load (not write)

Comment: Sure， Thanks @OneCricketeer.

Answer (score 0):

The specific term you are looking for is a `(pipelined) region`. It has some nice properties when it comes to [failovers](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/dev/task_failure_recovery.html#restart-pipelined-region-failover-strategy).